# Applying filter "Less-than or equal" to an URL

Tags: ios, swift

I bumped into an annoying problem today. I'm doing an app that queries an homemade API and parse the answer, a very classic one.

But due to the huge data that I'm receiving, I'd like to apply a filter "<=" and ">=" to my request, and it doesn't work. The URL object resulting is `nil`.

Here's the code :

```
print(request.url)      // prints the expected URL
var uerel = URL(string: request.url)
print(uerel)            // prints 'nil'
```

Output:

```
https://XXXXXXX.eu/YYYYYY?my_filter_id=5b057e27443318329d694d64&date>=2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z&date<=2016-01-01T20:00:00.000Z
nil
```

The thing intriguing is if I remove the `<` and the `>`, it works like a charm.
I tried to search in the [official doc for URL object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url) but it doesn't seem to need a special encoding .. ?

I also took a look at the RFC 1808 as mentioned in the said Official Documentation and these special characters are marked as `punctuation` so I believe it is OK to put them in an URL.

Where does the problem come from ?

Comment: The idea is that you pass the params/values encoded in the url (known as query parameters) (`startDate=...`, `endDate=...`) and you handle the filtering in the backend based on the values... You are not supposed to encode any "logic" in the url...

Comment: To be honest, I'm a bit new to the ```backend```thing and I'm not the developer of the API, I thought I could make that possible simply by putting these in the URL (works in PostMan) ..
Isn't there any other way to do it other than filtering in the backend side, even if it isn't the way to do it ? (I'm quite short on the deadline, I could fix this after it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to encode that URL since the `<` and `>` signs are not valid in a `URL`.

```
let unencodedUrlString = "https://XXXXXXX.eu/YYYYYY?my_filter_id=5b057e27443318329d694d64&date>=2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z&date<=2016-01-01T20:00:00.000Z"
guard let encodedUrlString = unencodedUrlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed), let url = URL(string: encodedUrlString) else { return }
```

The encoded URL will not contain the `<` and `>` symbols as you can see:

> https://XXXXXXX.eu/YYYYYY?my_filter_id=5b057e27443318329d694d64&date%3E=2016-01-01T08:00:00.000Z&date%3C=2016-01-01T20:00:00.000Z

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed this part since they don't mention it at all in the official doc of ```URL``` object (which is normal now that I think of it, it has nothing to do with it).

I now have a problem with my iOS app but this specific problem is solved. Thanks again !